# Do i need to download Linux?

Tags: ros, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Or is ROS a flavor of Unix, similar to Ubuntu?

Do i need any background before getting into ROS?

Will becoming proficient in ROS be enough to land me a job or are other skills needed, if so, please list them/common ones?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301351/do-i-need-to-download-linux?/) by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-08-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
@ros1423: you closed this as a "duplicate question".

Of what do you believe this is a duplicate question?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-05**:
Unfortunately we don't delete questions here.

Can you clarify why you want it deleted?

**Comment by [CharlieMAC](https://answers.ros.org/users/32694/charliemac/) on 2018-09-05**:
I´d say you should open a new question including your third question, but elaborate it, because it could lead to opinion-based answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Do i need to download Linux? Or is ROS a flavor of Unix, similar to Ubuntu?

ROS is not a stand-alone operating system, so yes, you'll have to install (after downloading) an appropriate base OS. Linux (in the form of Ubuntu) is one of the most used ones with ROS, but others can be made to work as well.

> Do i need any background before getting into ROS?

I believe #q288374 could clear this up.

> Will becoming proficient in ROS be enough to land me a job or are other skills needed, if so, please list them/common ones?

Not sure I can answer this. "becoming proficient in ROS" means a lot of different things to a lot of different people.

---

> Will going through the tutorial and installation guide show me how to download Ubuntu, or am I supposed to do that myself?

Yes, you'll have to first install a supported OS yourself. That is not part of the installation guide of ROS (this makes sense: separation of responsibilities implies that we keep information there where it is most appropriate, so we don't provide you with installation guides for software that is not ROS).

> And as for the job, I guess I'm asking if ROS itself is enough of a skill to get one a job or typically are other skills needed with it, and if so, which ones?

Perhaps a look at the *jobs* category on ROS Discourse can help here: see [discourse.ros.org/jobs](https://discourse.ros.org/c/jobs).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-23**:
Thanks. Will going through the tutorial and installation guide show me how to download Ubuntu, or am I supposed to do that myself?

And as for the job, I guess I'm asking if ROS itself is enough of a skill to get one a job or typically are other skills needed with it, and if so, which ones?

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thanks again. Any easy to follow guides you recd on downloading Linux?

And how much space do I need on my pc for it?

How much space does a typical ROS file take?

Have you been working with Robots long, would you be open to mentoring me?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
re: guides: the Ubuntu site has one. It's not too complicated.

re: space: this depends on how many pkgs you install. I'd expect around 5 GB would be more than enough for ROS proper.

re: robotics: yes.

re: mentoring: I'm afraid I won't have time for that.

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-24**:
Thanks for all your help. What about just high level mentoring? Not where we talk daily or even weekly, but like you guide me along, like first I complete the tutorial on here, then after that you point me in another direction, then again once I complete that, you guide me to another direction...?

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-24**:
im looking at ubunutu installation process and it says I can install it onto a flashstick or a dvd, even so I still need to partition part of my harddrive for saving files and all dont I? Or will the files within Ubuntu also be saved on my flash stick?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
I would really recommend you try and search for some information about Ubuntu installation elsewhere.

This site is about ROS support, not Ubuntu. You're far more likely to find good guidance on sites and fora dedicated to Ubuntu.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-24**:
@ros1423 learning ROS itself requires you to learn other areas as well depending on what you're doing with ROS. But every ROS project requires knowledge of C++/python/XML language and basics with bash and linux. Then it strongly depends on what you're trying to do.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-24**:
In regards to future job securing... it's like with every other job in the world... If you're good at it and someone needs your skills they can hire you. But being good at one thing still doesn't guarantee you a job. You also have to be able to work in team, solve problems on your own, come up...

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-24**:
with new ideas etc. Soft skills are also important. If you're not able to communicate with others in team you're slowing everybody down. So finding a job is not that simple. You can't just learn 1 skill and boom everybody wants you and will pay you millions of dollars. Especially in tech industry.

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-24**:
@GVDhoorn, thanks

@l4ncelot: I can use Python or C++ right? I dont need to use both? And if I want to become an AI engineer, what skills do I need, in general? I did some research and see Deep Learning, ROS, Python, Linux, a modeling tool like AutoMax 3DS.  What else would you add? And also would

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-24**:
you be open to mentoring me in ROS? Just provide high level guidance, that type of thing?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-26**:
@ros1423 Python is not required but it's good to know basics at least because some ROS packages are written in python. So you wouldn't be able to modify it or understand it without python basics. As it has been said already it really depends on what you're trying to achieve.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-26**:
I for example never used deep learning or automax and other things because I don't need those for my work. It's not like every engineer has the same type of skills because everybody needs something different based on project you're working on.

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-26**:
The best way to learn things is by doing them. So if don't have a job in the field right now grab a book and give yourself some little project where you can learn things on your own. Deep learning requires you to have advanced knowledge of mathematics. Google it on google scholar and you'll see.

**Comment by [ros1423](https://answers.ros.org/users/37127/ros1423/) on 2018-08-26**:
thanks. But don't I need Python or C++ so I can program in ROS? I need one to do anything in ROS right?

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2018-08-27**:
Yes, you can write your packages either in C++ or python (or both).